# Is there any way to fill values from a finer resolution grid to coarse resolution grid using nearest neighbour in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am working with MODIS active fire data (data resolution 1 km). After deriving meaningful information from it, I have with me an array of size (72x4797x4797) [time x lat x lon], and mesh for lat (4797 x 4797) and lon (4797 x 4797). The latitude mesh decrease from 40 N to O with uniform dy of 0.0108 so that mesh have values changing in rows while each column is same as other. However, the longitude mesh has values changing in rows and columns which I guess is because for each latitude, the value of longitude is different because of satellite swath.

My objective is to have this data on WRF grid (lat 129 x lon 109 at 30 km resolution). The data has NaN for all points with no fire and values at points of active fire. Using scipy interpolation with [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) returns an array of all NaNs which is of no use as all information is lost.

To make a coarse resolution data on new lat-lon, I am trying to have use a nearest neighbour approach, for example if multiple active fires are present in fine grid, assign that lat-lon to nearest coarse grid lat-lon while taking average of all such points in that coarse grid square.

In the code below,

- lon_wrf, lat_wrf are new longitude and latitude of interest at coarse
  resolution.
- lon_mosaic, lat_mosaic are both 2-D arrays of longitude
  and latitude at fine resolution.
- Block_OC_day is a 2-D array to be
  made on newer coarse resolution.

I am first finding all the locations of fire that are not NaN and extracting the lon and lat for these locations. Next I am finding the nearest lon and lat in target grid. The function gives me the indices and values. Next I would like is averaging the value of Block_OC_day on all points that have same lat-lon on target grid.

```
lat_1d = lat_mosaic[:,0]                          # making 2-D latitude mesh to 1-D
fire_loc = np.argwhere(~np.isnan(Block_OC_day))   # finding all locations with non-NaN

fire_lat = lat_1d[fire_loc[:,0]]                    # finding latitude of fine resolution
fire_lon = lon_mosaic[fire_loc[:,0],fire_loc[:,1]]  # finding longitue of fine resolution

# Function to find nearest values and index

def nearest(value_to_search,lookup_array):
    '''Finds nearest value and index closest to a value in an array'''
    
    idx = np.argmin(np.abs(lookup_array-value_to_search))
    closest_value = lookup_array[idx]
    
    return closest_value, idx

# Storing target latitude and index
va_lat = []
li_lat = []
for i in range(0,len(fire_lat)):
    a, idx = nearest(fire_lat[i],lat_wrf)
    va_lat.append(a)
    li_lat.append(idx)

# storing target longitude and index
va_lon = []
li_lon = []
for i in range(0,len(fire_lon)):
    a, idx = nearest(fire_lon[i],lon_wrf)
    va_lon.append(a)
    li_lon.append(idx)
```

Comment: Are you sure your hires fire data isn't already gridded, like Sinusoidal or something else? A direct translation would be much faster if possible. If the data is truly irregular you could consider something like `pykdtree` for a fast lookup.

Comment: @RutgerKassies yes the original data was in Sinusoidal projection. I have retrieved the lat-lon information using pyproj transform and combined them for multiple MODIS mosaics. The resultant lat-lon are both 2-D array

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to solve the problem. It involves finding common indices of lat-lon and then fill them with averaged values of all points in fine-grid.

There may be a better solution but this code works fine.

```
# Using specific indices
i = 108
j = 128

# np.argwhere(li_lon==i)
# np.argwhere(li_lat == j)
inter = np.intersect1d(np.argwhere(li_lon==i), np.argwhere(li_lat == j))  # finding locations to replace
# fire_lon[inter]
# fire_lat[inter]
NoNaNFire = Block_OC_day[~np.isnan(Block_OC_day)]   # extracting values at those locations
AvgFire = np.nanmean(NoNaNFire[inter])  # averaging all fine-grid points
# AvgFire returns the average value of variable at i and j of coarse grid

# For any 2-D coarse grid
Block_WRF = np.empty((lat_wrf.shape[0],lon_wrf.shape[0]))
for i in range(0,len(lon_wrf)):
     for j in range(0,len(lat_wrf)):
         inter = np.intersect1d(np.argwhere(li_lon==i), np.argwhere(li_lat == j))
         Block_WRF[j,i] = np.nanmean(NoNaNFire[inter])
```